# asp.net button appears enabled but does not react to mouse hover or click

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have cmdCancel and cmdLaunchReport buttons that appear enabled, but do not react to mouse hover nor mouse click.  I can tab to these buttons to get focus there and then press keyboard [Enter]-key to send postback to server.

There is similar code (nearly identical with DIV rather than ASP.PANEL surrounding the two buttons), and those other pages work as expected.
I have checked the code-behind and server-code and there is no code referencing the panel nor the buttons nor the div(s).

What else could I look for to uncover the fault with this rather routine set of code?
Your comments are welcome.
Here is the aspx:

```
<div id="pagingdiv" class="RPT_PagingDIV" >
   <asp:Panel ID="divRptActionButtons" runat="server"  style="float: left; margin-left: 0em;" Enabled="true" >
      <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" SkinID="cmdButton" Text="Close" Style="margin-left: 0.5em;" Enabled="true" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdLaunchReport" runat="server" SkinID="cmdButton" Text="Print, Email or Save to Disk" Style="margin-left: 0.5em;" />
   </asp:Panel>
   <div id="divRptPaging" style="float: left; text-align: center; width: 70%;">
      <span style="font-size: larger;">Report page navigation:</span>
      <asp:DataPager ID="pagerReport" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvwReportData" PageSize="1">
         <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button"
               FirstPageText="First Page" LastPageText="Last Page" NextPageText="Next Page" PreviousPageText="Previous Page"
               ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True"
               ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowPreviousPageButton="true" />
            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="20" RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="true"
               NumericButtonCssClass="RPT_PagingNumberOther"
               CurrentPageLabelCssClass="RPT_PagingNumberCurrent"
               NextPreviousButtonCssClass="fciBUTTON01" />
         </Fields>
      </asp:DataPager>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRowBeg" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRowMax" runat="server" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post the script also ?

Comment: You are missing subscribing to `click` events for these buttons. Look at my answer for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire up the buttons inside the `Panel` with click event handlers. If you do that then things will work without any issues.  Note the `OnClick` attribute in code below which you need to add, and also create corresponding methods in code behind.

**Markup**

```
 <asp:Panel ID="divRptActionButtons" runat="server"  style="float: left; margin-left: 0em;" Enabled="true" >
      <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" SkinID="cmdButton" Text="Close" 
           Style="margin-left: 0.5em;" Enabled="true"
           OnClick="cmdCancel_Click"/>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdLaunchReport" runat="server" SkinID="cmdButton"
           Text="Print, Email or Save to Disk" Style="margin-left: 0.5em;"
           OnClick="cmdLaunchReport_Click" />
   </asp:Panel>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //some code here
}

protected void cmdLaunchReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //some code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have taken your solution and it does not help.  I am familiar with this click-pattern. What occurs is the buttons appear on the page, but the HOVER and CLICK are NOT reacting at all.  The buttons seem to be disabled, BUT they are NOT since I  can TAB to each of them and press the ENTER-key to invoke the click event which posts back to the server and the cmdCancel_Click event is executed.  When I use the mouse and click on the button NOTHING happens, it does not get depressed. It does not react to the mouse-click.

Comment: Further information for you...AJAX UpdatePanel wraps the aspx code, so no need for OnClick= in the buttons.

Comment: Protected Sub cmdCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click
      ' Remove session variables used by this page.
      Me.DoClose()

      ' Return to parent page.
      sbRedirect("~\Reports01.aspx")

   End Sub     /// as stated originally this code works on other pages and when ENTER-key is pressed.  Mouse events are somehow disabled and I do not know what causes this.

Comment: Ok.Can you post the markup of update panel? There could be something there.

Comment: Also, make sure whether the click event is executed or not, by stepping through the code-behind when each of the buttons inside asp panel are clicked. Sometimes, due to ajax nature of post back, it might appear that nothing  has happened even when code-behind has executed.

Comment: @Sunil...thank you for your reply. The aspx is too large to post here over 200 lines of code.  However, I tried your suggestion and put a break-point on the very first line of code in the Page_Load()-event.  Once the page is shown, I click on the close-button and NOTHING is posted back to the server. This is expected since the mouse does not affect the button at all as noted repeatedly during this post.  I will try looking at the "Enabled" property of the cmdCancel-button and it's parent container. thanks.

Comment: @JohnD, Check if there is a JavaScript error when you first tried to click on the problem button. If there is a JavaScript error then the post back process is interrupted. You can verify this by opening your site in Google Chrome browser, press Ctrl+Shift+I to bring up the dev tools and then select the Console tab in dev tools . After this, click on the problem button and see if Console tab shows something in red. If yes, then you have a JavaScript error and that is the cause of your problems.